# Flash plugin not working in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, google-chrome, flash, plugins, streaming

I cannot play Amazon music library in Ubuntu 16.04 (64-bit) with google chrome Version 64.0.3282.186 (Official Build) (64-bit). I have installed flashplugin-installer. I get the error message **Adobe Flash is Disabled** when loading the site: https://music.amazon.in/.
Although I give the option for run flash this time, it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Google Chrome has flash built-in, so whatever the reason for your problem is, it has nothing to do with `flashplugin-installer`.

Comment: I'm facing the same problem and I'm seeing some very old questions regarding the same, so I don't think it will be solved soon.